# NestJS: How to get ExecutionContext in Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

We are using NestJS for our NodeJS application.
In our app we have some middlewares/guards/interceptors to create a user-request-context, validate jwt token, intercept request/response, etc.

We also implemented some custom decorators, to set metadata for our endpoints.
It's very easy to use this data in guards / intercetpors, because you have the ExecutionContext in canActivate / intercept functions.

But we are deeply missing this functionality in middlewares.
**Is there any chance to get / inject the ExecutionContext in a NestJS middleware?**

e.g.

```
export class SomeMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor(@Inject('ExecutionContext') context: ExecutionContext) {}

    use(req, res, next) {
        // get data from context / decorator
        Reflect.getMetadata(SOME_KEY, context.getHandler());

        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: According to NestJS docs, it seems middleware is executed before an ExecutionContext is created. No direct mention of this in the docs, but there are multiple hints that this is how it's designed.

Comment: Did you find any way to read metadata in the Middleware?

Comment: No, it's not possible, according to the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context): "These utilities provide information about the current execution context which can be used to build generic guards, filters, and interceptors that can work across a broad set of controllers, methods, and execution contexts." So it's available in guards, filters, and interceptors, not in middleware. You can add something to your `req` object, and check it in a global guard though for example

Comment: An execution context is not yet created when the middleware is running. You can, however, use the `req` (request) object

Answer (score -1):

You can use `cls-hooked` or other similar modules to create custom contexts. For that, you can have a context creator middleware like:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import cls from 'cls-hooked';

@Injectable()
export class ContextCreatorMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private readonly contextNamespace: cls.Namespace<Record<string, any>>;

  constructor() {
    this.contextNamespace =
      cls.getNamespace('context-name') ||
      cls.createNamespace('context-name');
  }

  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    this.requestTracingNamespace.bindEmitter(req);
    this.requestTracingNamespace.bindEmitter(res);

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.contextNamespace.run(async () => {
        this.contextNamespace.set('YOUR_KEY', YOUR_VALUE);
        resolve(next());
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Then you can use your context in other services like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import cls from 'cls-hooked';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {
  public constructor() {}

  public f1() {
    const contextNamespace = cls.getNamespace('context-name');
    const yourValue = contextNamespace?.get('YOUR_KEY');
  }
}
```

Remember to apply the middleware in your AppModule:

```
export class AppModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(ContextCreatorMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```